# Is it safe to use an exception outside the catch statement if it is held in a std::exception_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have a `std::exception_ptr` with an exception inside it. I am going to invoke `std::rethrow_exception` to get the actual exception, will the exception be valid after the catch statement? My guess here is that since I still hold the `std::exception_ptr` it will still be valid.

See the example:

```
std::exception_ptr ePtr = initialize_somewhere_else();
std::runtime_error* a=NULL;
try {
    std::rethrow_exception(ePtr);
} catch(std::runtime_error& e) {
    a = &e;
}
std::cout << a << ", " << a->what() << std::endl;
```

Note: In my tests using Clang this does work.

Comment: I think this is what `std::current_exception()` is for, to capture the current exception to be used outside of the catch scope.

Comment: @JustSid Yes, but I was wondering about the concrete object, not the pointer wrapper.

Comment: I would say this is undefined behaviour, since `e` is in the catch scope, and you take a pointer to it and then use it in the functions scope. This is just a guess though, I haven't checked the standard.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt it is formally allowed.  In practice, I can imagine the exception throw creating a local copy and handing you a reference to it, then disposing of it at the end of the `catch` scope.

Comment: @Yakk The cppreference.com states "The exception object referenced by an std::exception_ptr remains valid as long as there remains at least one std::exception_ptr that is referencing it: std::exception_ptr is a shared-ownership smart pointer.", but it is not clear for me if it meant the object in the catch when saying "exception object".

Comment: @AndréPuel *nod*.  There might be freedom for the compiler to copy (or even move!) the exception object into the local scope before passing you the reference in the `catch`, or not do it.  There might be freedom to do even stranger things.  You'd have to look at the standard text for what the thing referred to in the `catch` is, and how it is connected to what `exception_ptr` refers to formally, and how their lifetimes relate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find much detail in the Standard about what `rethrow_exception` actually does. But the specification for `exception_ptr` contains a (non-normative) note that says: *"if rethrow_exception rethrows the same exception object (rather
than a copy) [...]"* so I think we cannot rely on `e` referring to the exception object `ePtr` points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to use an exception outside the catch statement if it is held in a std::exception_ptr?

<del>Yes.  You can think of `exception_ptr` as a reference-counted pointer to the exception.  The exception will live for as long as an `exception_ptr` refers to it, and no longer.</del>

<del>Additionally, `rethrow_exception` does not make a copy.</del>

Sorry, I think I've given an incorrect answer.

Here is a detection test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>


int
main()
{
    auto ePtr = std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error("some text"));
    std::runtime_error* a = nullptr;
    try
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(ePtr);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        a = &e;
    }
    *a = std::runtime_error("other text");
    try
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(ePtr);
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

On gcc and clang this outputs:

```
other text
```

This indicates that `a` and `ePtr` refer to the exact same object.

However VS, current version according to http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net outputs:

```
some text
```

This indicates that `a` and `ePtr` refer to different objects.

The question now is whether VS is conforming in this regard.  My opinion is that it doesn't really matter.  This is a contentious area of the standard, and if contested, the standard will be changed to match existing practice.

It appears to me that `rethrow_exception` makes a copy on VS, and that implies that the lifetime of `e` in the original question is not guaranteed to be tied to `ePtr`.