# May I modify the value of an exception inside a std::exception_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

If I have a exception stored inside `std::exception_ptr`. I rethrow the exception using `std::rethrow_exception`, access it using `catch(MyException&)` and then I modify the value.

If I throw the same exception again, should I observe the modification I made?

The following code demonstrate my idea:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct MyException {
    int value;
};

int main() {
    std::exception_ptr a = std::make_exception_ptr(MyException());

    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(a);
    } catch(MyException& b) {
        std::cout << b.value << std::endl;
        b.value = 3;
    }

    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(a);
    } catch(MyException& b) {
        std::cout << b.value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by observe the modification ?

Comment: @perencia If I rethrow the same exception, it would have the modifications i made. In my code sample, the second time I throw `a` I have 3 in `value`.

Comment: In the example you are always using the same object, catching it by reference.

Comment: He did not prove it at all.

Comment: Prove is a strong word. Just because it works on my compiler and on my platform does not mean that it is correct according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Sure: The 'a' is a reference to the exception thrown around (but your design purpose might be questionable)

Comment: A question is, is it ok for the exception handling code to copy the exception into a local variable, give `MyException& b` a reference to that, then discard it at the end of the catch?

Comment: @Yakk I am sure no implementation would do that, as it is an unnecessary overhead. But, it is not clear for me if the standard would disallow such behaviour. However, if I had to guess I would say that the standard is flexible enough to allow such copy before the catch statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>Your code is conforming and portable.</del>  But there be dragons here:

- If you obtain your `exception_ptr` via `current_exception()`, it is unspecified whether you get a reference to a copy of the current exception, or a reference to the current exception itself.  Even if you call `current_exception()` twice in a row, you may or may not get a reference to the same exception object.
- Since `exception_ptr` is copyable, and copies *may* point to the same exception object, and `rethrow_exception` doesn't make a copy, it is quite possible for two threads to throw the same exception object simultaneously.  So in a multi-threaded program, it can be very difficult to know if you have unique access to an exception within a `catch` clause.  Modifications to that exception may produce a data race.  That data race may exist on some platforms, and not on others, depending on whether `current_exception()` makes a copy or not.

So if you must modify an exception object in a multi-threaded program, it is safest to copy it first, modify the copy, and then rethrow the copy (if necessary).

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I have given an incorrect answer.

Using:  http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net  the output of the example code is:

```
0
0
```

The VS implementation of `rethrow_exception` appears to make a copy of the exception.

Clang and gcc do not make copies.

Comment: So there cannot be a copy on rethrow exception?

Comment: @Yakk:  That's the way I read [propagation]/p10: *Throws:* the exception object to which `p` refers.  Conversely p8 in describing `current_exception()`  goes to great lengths in describing the unspecified copy semantics.

Comment: Based on your answer, could I infer the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462906/is-it-safe-to-use-an-exception-outside-the-catch-statement-if-it-is-held-in-a-st "Yes. it is safe"?